Are these depictions of ancient Greek and Roman libraries "scroll-shelves" historically accurate?
In some modern depictions of ancient Greek and Roman libraries or studies, I sometimes see shelving units specifically designed for scrolls.
These feature cubby-hole style compartments of squarish slots where scrolls are neatly arranged. These cubby-hole compartments often have a very specific shape, resembling squares rotated by 45 degrees, creating a diamond-like appearance. Sometimes these sections are also sectioned horizontally.
Here are some pictures for clarity:



I'm curious about the historical accuracy of these "scroll-shelves." Specifically:

Is there any archaeological evidence for such shelving units in
ancient Greek or Roman contexts?

If these depictions are not historically accurate, how were scrolls
typically stored and organized in ancient Greek and Roman libraries?

When and why did the concept of these "scroll-shelves" emerge in
popular depictions of the ancient world?



Excellent question! As soon as I read it, I realized I've been wondering about that myself. (I hope the answer will also tell us something about how we have come to know it.)

There's a popular history of bookshelves which looks like it may reference some relevant sources and details about ancient scroll storage.

https://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/scroll/scrollcodex.html states: "Scrolls were stacked horizontally on a shelf or stored upright in a cylindrical book-box (capsa), which was fitted with a lid and straps for carrying (the scrinium was a larger container). According to Pliny, the only wood suitable for such capsae was beech, which could be thinly-cut (XVI.lxxxiii.229)." But no direct reference for the initial assertions on storage.

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/libraries-used-to-chain-their-books-to-shelves-with-the-spines-hidden-away-4392158/ and https://brewminate.com/storing-and-accessing-books-in-ancient-libraries/ may also be of interest.

Question is copied from reddit here.

@justCal Yes, I'm the OP of that post. I posted this question here too to hopefully show it to people that might not be on that subreddit

Good question; please cite the images to avoid the appearance of plagiarism

At the Villa of the Papyri in Herculanium, 1,500 ancient scrolls have been found, covered by the Eruption of Vesuvius in 79.

At the time of the eruption of Vesuvius in AD 79, the valuable library was packed in cases ready to be moved to safety when it was overtaken by a pyroclastic flow; the eruption eventually deposited some 20–25 m of volcanic ash over the site, charring the scrolls but preserving them – the only surviving library of Antiquity – as the ash hardened to form tuff.1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_of_the_Papyri#Epicureanism_and_the_library
This says nothing about how the scrolls were normally stored when not being moved.
But this says:

In the living quarters, bath installations were brought to light, and the library of rolled and carbonised papyri placed inside wooden capsae, some of them on ordinary wooden shelves and around the walls and some on the two sides of a set of shelves in the middle of the room.1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_of_the_Papyri#Layout
So this suggests there were shelves of some type in the library.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/25542290

This doesn't answer the question.

Johann Heinrich Winckelmann, when visiting the site in 1752, 2 years after the excavation, gives a short description of the room then understood to be the library. "All round the wall were cupboards, as is customary in archives, at man's height, and in the centre of the room stood another such rack for writings on either side, so that one could walk about freely. The wood of these racks was burnt to coals, and, as one can easily see, collapsed when one touched them."

+1 for being as closest we have to an actual answer to the question. At least, now we know that there were "ordinary" shelves and cupboards in some ancient libraries.

@Astor Florida  I don't know the anser to the question.    But until  andunless a Roman archaeologist nswers the question it might be a good idea to research the Villa of the Papyri to find out more about the shelving.

Designs were varied, just like today. Search for specific designs of:

Armaria: wooden cupboards or cabinets with multiple shelves. Scrolls were placed horizontally on the shelves. The armaria were often placed against the walls of the library. Designs vary.
Niches: the famous Library of Celsus in Ephesus had wall niches to store the scrolls.
Capsores or capsa: cylindrical boxes used for transporting but also storing individual scrolls.

For references see:

Casson, Lionel. Libraries in the Ancient World. Yale University
Press, 2001.
Johnson, Elmer D. History of Libraries in the Western World. Scarecrow Press, 2001.
http://ancientcataloging.weebly.com/rome.html

